# Como acessar o valor desse array em javascript?

Tags: javascript

Bom dia, estou querendo acessar os dados desse array em javascript

```
[{"nome":"Teste","descricao":"Apenas um Teste","ativo":"1","id":6},[{"nome":"Categoria"}]]
```

e não estou conseguindo, a maneira que estou utilizando é `console.log(var[0].nome)`, no console exibi como undefined

@edit

meus código javascript

```
function criaProduto(){
            prod = {
                nome: $('#nomeProduto').val() ,
                descricao: $('#descProduto').val(),
                codigo_barra: $('#codProduto').val(),
                ativo: 1,
                categoria_id: $('#categoriaProduto').val()
            };
            //console.log(prod);
            $.post("/api/produtos", prod, function(data){
                console.log(data)
                console.log(data[0]['nome'])
            });
        }
```

e php que faz a inserção dos dados e da o retorno

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $prod = new Produto();
        $prod->nome = $request->input('nome');
        $prod->descricao = $request->input('descricao');
        $prod->codigo_barra = $request->input('codigo_barra');
        $prod->ativo = $request->input('ativo');
        $prod->categoria_id = $request->input('categoria_id');
        $prod->save();
        $cat_id = $request->input('categoria_id');
        $cat = Categoria::select('nome')->where('id', $cat_id)->get();
        $teste = array($prod, $cat);
        return json_encode($teste);
    }
```

Agradeço desde já

Comment: Marque a resposta correta quando houver uma, por favor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema é que você não está fazendo a análise do JSON obtido do servidor e por isso recebe `undefined` quando faz `console.log(var[0].nome)`. Use o método [`JSON.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) para analisar uma string JSON, construindo o valor ou um objeto JavaScript descrito pela string.

```js
const json = '[{"nome":"Teste","descricao":"Apenas um Teste","ativo":"1","id":6},[{"nome":"Categoria"}]]';

//Aqui faz a analise do JSON
const obj = JSON.parse(json);

//Descomente a próxima linha para "desfazer a análise do JSON" e obter o comportamento descrito na pergunta
//obj = json;

console.log(obj[0].nome);

console.log(obj[0].descricao);

console.log(obj[1][0].nome);
```

Comment: conseguir acessar o obj[0].nome mas obj[1].nome da como undefined... desculpa se for erro besta meu, mas pelo retorno ele aparece como se fosse um array dentro do outro, estou meio confuso rs, vou tentar copiar o código e anexa na minha pergunta

Comment: @Faillen, Olha a sintaxe do seu JSON para para `obj[1]`, o valor está contido dentro de um  outro array você vai ter que acessar assim obj[1][0].nome ou então ajuste a formação do JSON no PHP

Comment: é consegui aqui, com obj[1][0].nome, obrigado, desculpa pelas perguntas de iniciante

Answer (score 3):

Você vai acessar da mesma forma que no php:

```js
var array = [{"nome":"Teste","descricao":"Apenas um Teste","ativo":"1","id":6},[{"nome":"Categoria"}]]

console.log(array[0]['nome'])
```

Comment: atualizei minha pergunta, pois estou começando a achar que estou retornando errado... pois deu undefined nesse metodo que você passou

Answer (score 0):

se você estiver buscando o json via ajax, tente algo do tipo:

```
$.ajax({ type: "GET",   
     url: url,
     async: false,
     success : function(text)
     {
        response = text;
        if(jQuery.isEmptyObject(response)){
           alert('erro!');
        } else {
        console.log(response[0].nome)
     },
     error: function() { 
     } }).responseText;
```